# Check certain text from a webpage via powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to get the HTML code from an Intranet webpage and monitor if certain texts or titles exist. This powershell code will be used by my monitoring program to trigger alerts when the webpage is down so that I cannot see that certain texts or titles.

For now, I'm just using Write-Host to see if my piece of code works. I can now extract the HTML source to `$output`, and I am sure 'Create!' can be found inside. However, I'm not getting a 'YES'.

May I know if `$output` can be checked by using `-contains`?

Thank you very much for your help!

```
$targetUrl  = 'https://myUrl/'
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate($targetUrl)

while($ie.Busy) {
     Start-Sleep -m 2000
}

$output = $ie.Document.body.innerHTML

if($output -contains '*Create!*')
{Write-Host 'YES'}
else
{Write-Host 'NO'}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `-match` instead: `$output -match 'Create!'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) is used to search collections. The IE's innerHTML is just a string:

```
$output = $ie.Document.body.innerHTML
$output.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Use pattern matching operators like, well, `-like` and `-match`.

By the way, if IE is not mandatory, try [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

Comment: I also tried below as well, but I'm getting an error.

    `$URI = "https://myURL/"`
    `$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI`

Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At HTML_testing_2.ps1:2 char:9
+ $HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @Felix Wong: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.